# Search date in mysql date time column

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a table in **MYSQL** database with a column db_date with type is **datetime** ex:**2016-10-20 01:05:00**

I use a **PHP** code to search different thing the date is one of them for that i use a date picker have the date like this **10/21/2016** **m/d/Y**

for that i use this to transform this form to the form in database

```
STR_TO_DATE('".$date."','%m/%d/%Y')
```

The Problem is that when i use `db_date= STR_TO_DATE('".$date."','%m/%d/%Y')` it give only the date that have hour and minutes and second **00:00:00**

but i want all the date ex: if i choose **10/20/2016** i want all date with different time in database be selected

i tried to use the `date` function in mysql but i didn't have result
 **date(STR_TO_DATE('".$date."','%m/%d/%Y'))**

And also i tried to use the **DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('".$date."','%m/%d/%Y'))**
and i didn't have a result

the query will be like this `$query=SELECT * FROM tbl_staff {$sql}`

and this is the code

```
$q = array();    
    $sql = "";
    if(isset($_POST['txt_date']) && !empty($_POST['txt_date'])){  
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txt_date']); 
    $q[] = " db_date=STR_TO_DATE('".$date."','%m/%d/%Y') and db_status!='Done' AND db_status!='Cancelled'";      
    }
```

How can i solve this problem ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can use format in datapicker to customise the date :

```
$('#date').datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
```

And for your sql query do (use date() for db_date)

```
$q[] = " DATE(db_date)= $date and db_status!='Done' AND db_status!='Cancelled'";
```